# Access inline event object function body without 'function' constructor javascript

Tags: javascript, function, events, inline

I am filtering a bunch of objects using jQuery, and I want to have access to the function body of the event without the function constructor attached to it.  I'll show you what I mean:

```
 $('li').filter(function(){
        return this.onmouseout !== null;
        })
        .each(function(){
               console.log(this.onmouseout);
        });
```

What get's returned is:

```
    function onmouseout(event) {
         GoodSearchBadgeHideMenu('120');
    }
```

What I would like to get returned is:

```
    GoodSearchBadgeHideMenu('120'); 

   \\notice the absence of 'function onmouseout(event)' and closing bracket
```

I'm sure I could use `String.replace()` to easily parse this, but I want to know if the function body is accessible somewhere in the element's attributes or in the event object.

Thanks

Comment: You're saying "inline event object function body". What do you mean by "inline"? Is it assigned as an attribute? If so, use `this.getAttribute("onmouseout");`

Comment: So, what exactly do you want? Can you show the desired output?

Comment: @Crazy Train got it.  Put it as an answer and I'll accept it.  I'll edit the post to show desired output for future generations.  And @Crazy Train, what I meant by inline is that it is attached to an element like `'<li onmouseout="`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you're attaching the handlers as element attributes, you can use `.getAttribute()` to retrieve the body that was set.

```
this.getAttribute("onmouseout");
```

So...

```
 $('li').filter(function(){
            return this.onmouseout !== null;
        })
        .each(function(){
            console.log(this.getAttribute("onmouseout"));
        });
```